# I have a black goop coming out of my shower head

Tags: plumbing-fixture

Black gunk is in shower head It is also in my sink drain, but the shower head is disturbing. We have city water. What could it bed it be?

Comment: Welcome. You should tell us more about the situation. Where are you? When did this start happening? What kind of plumbing do you have? A photo would be helpful, too, or at least a description more informative than "goop".

Comment: We need a little more information... Take a few pictures...  has there been any work done on your plumbing?  Has you water been off for a while?  Is this a new problem?

Comment: Is there any odor to it? Like hydrogen sulfide (rotten egg smell)?   If so you might have anaerobic bacteria buildup that has come loose in your plumbing. Let us know more details so we can better help you.

Comment: Hi, smell. It used to be just flaky but recently turned sludgy

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include as much detail (like what kind of smell - does it smell like rotten eggs, like swamp water, sea water, something else?) as you possibly can. The more details, the more likely that someone will be able to help you. Also, details tend to get lost down here in the comments, and not everybody reads all the comments before answering or moving on.

Comment: No smell, I couldn't edit it when I realized the no didn't print :(